# Can Wicket handle two requests from the same page within the same session concurrently?

Tags: java, session, servlets, concurrency, wicket

When I click on link 1 and then, before the response was received, click on link 2 on the same page, I get a "Page Expired" error from Wicket. Is Wicket conceptional capable to do such a concurrent processing?

Any ideas why Wicket loses the session (it seems to reside on tomcat though)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question myself: It seems like Wicket has no problem to process a second link click while the first is still beeing processed. I tried it with the following example.

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.Link;
import org.apache.wicket.model.IModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;

public class ConcurrentClickPage extends WebPage {

    public ConcurrentClickPage() {
        final IModel<String> model = new Model<String>("initial");
        Label status = new Label("status", model);
        add(status);
        add(new Link("link1"){
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ConcurrentClickPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                model.setObject("link 1 clicked");
            }
        });
        add(new Link("link2"){
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                model.setObject("link 2 clicked");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And the corresponding html page:

```
<html>
  <body>
      <span wicket:id="status">text</span>
      <p>
          <a href="#" wicket:id="link1">Link 1 (deferred processing)</a><br/>
          <a href="#" wicket:id="link2">Link 2</a>
      </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I click on link 1 and click on link 2 while waiting on the response of link 1, everything is fine and I get no "page expired" error.